# Can a capacitor store enough energy to heat a piece of metal?

Tags: capacitor

I want to design a circuit that uses the power stored in a capacitor to heat up a piece of metal to the point where it starts to glow yellow.

Assuming the capacitor is charged to 10 V, what capacity is needed to have enough energy that a single discharge event heats a piece of metal?

For the purpose of narrowing down the experiment, let's assume the piece of metal is the wire in a 5 A, T-type (time-lag), 5 x 20 mm fuse like this:

[image]

Comment: This is the definition of a badly asked question.

Comment: @Rev1.0 It was the definition of a badly asked question. At the risk of adding specifics that do not agree to the intention of the original poster, I have edited the text so someone can start explaining. Once we have, for example, an explanation including the thermal capacity of the fuse's wire, we can still extend the gained knowledge to calculating what capacitor would be needed if we were to heat up an entire railroad rail, and get into the details why a voltage greater than 10V helps a great deal (E=CU^2/2)...

Comment: Yes. It's called a flashgun. The old type with magnesium wire in a one-use bulb.

Answer (score 1):

The component that you need is a resistor. But I think you will find out that to store the energy required to heat something to a significant degree you need an impractically large capacitor.

Comment: Sorry for the ongemak; I have edited the original question because it would have been a candidate for getting closed as it stood.

Comment: You don't need too large of a cap to light up a tiny incandescent light for a moment or two. :)